# jQuery $.post() in recursive way (loop)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I learn jQuery and don't understand this situation:

**When running this code  in debug mode all work well. But when running this code normal, calback function don't starts.** Why?
In non debug mode I have ->  "Start" -> "End 10"

Browser: Google Chrome.

```
var nrPost = 10;

$("#buttnX").click(function() {
    alert("Start");     
    GoPosts();
    End();
}); 

function End() {
    alert('End ' + nrPost);
};

function GoPosts() {
    $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
    var url = "http://......";
    var data = { ... };
    $.post(url, data, Callback, 'json');
};

function Callback(response) {   
    if (response.error) {
        return;
    }

    nrPost--;

    if (nrPost > 0) [
        GoPosts();
    } else {
        return;
    }
};
```

Comment: What are you referring to by 'debug mode'?

Comment: Google chrome have "Inspect element" and there is tab "Scrips". and when I click my javascript code execute, (this tool also have breakpoints and I use it end execute code step by step with F10 and F11 ... ). I am new in this world.

Comment: I can only guess but could you precise if the output you expect is "Start" -> "End 0"?

Comment: Yes, Expect "Start" -> "End 0".

Comment: **This code is well, problem is in my URL when I do second post it respons an error (this error came from speed of post on server)**

Answer (score 3):

You had an extra }; in your code.  I changed it around a bit to use jQuery and put it up on jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rH8RV/19/

It should alert: "Start" and then "End 10", that's correct based on how you wrote your code.  Were you expecting anything else?

Comment: Yes, I expect do Callback 10 times, until nrPost=0; because a call GoPosts(); every time when nrPost is bigger than 0.

Comment: You can even streamline this a bit by making it one function. [http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/rH8RV/8/]

Comment: @Artiom: Ok, updated it to show you that it is calling it 10 times.  I just added an alert in the Callback method.  Note: I'm using jsfiddle's ajax testing url: '/echo/json/', disregard that if you copy out the code. http://jsfiddle.net/rH8RV/19/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're planning to do with your recursive implementation, but if that's all, you could actually do this:

```
function startLoop(nrPost) {

    // No need to put this in a loop
    $.ajaxSetup({ async: false });

    for (var i = 0; i < nrPost; i++) {
        alert('Start ' + i);

        var url = 'http://......';
        var data = {};

        $.post(url, data, function (response) {
            if (response.error)
                return;

            alert('End ' + i);
        }, 'json');
    }
}

$('#buttnX').click(function () { startLoop(10) });
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but a need recursive; because my recursive loop depends on response of in callback.

Comment: Well, this is just as hierarchical as your example, but you know your code best :)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are expecting the display to be:

- "Start"
- "End 0"

This is unlikely to work with your solution.

Your Ajax call `$.post(url, data, Callback, 'json');` is asynchronous. This means that once the `$.post` method returns, the request is sent to the URL you have provided. However, `Callback` is not called until JQuery receives the answers. What happens immediately is that `GoPosts` terminates and the program continues. It comes back to line 5 of your code, inside the anonymous function in your click handler. At that point, `End()` is called and alerts "End 10".

You probably want to put your call to `End` in `Callback` instead:

```
function Callback(response)
{   
    if (response.error) 
    {
        return;
    }

    nrPost--;

    if(nrPost>0)
        GoPosts();
    else
    {
        End(); // You only want to end once you have made you nrPost calls to GoPost
        return;
    }
};
```

Comment: "Your Ajax call $.post(url, data, Callback, 'json'); is asynchronous."      $.ajaxSetup({async:false}); and this what do?

Comment: I want only execute GoPost() until nrPost is more tath 0

Comment: I think that `async: false` only works if you use `$.ajax`. I don't think it works with `$.post`